# Remove duplicates but keep first and last record of sequence

Tags: python, bash, perl, awk, duplicates

If input file is:

```
400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,6:50,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,7:00,90002107,4
400102-25,7:05,90002111,5
400102-25,7:05,90002106,6
6004-10,13:05,90006017,1
6004-10,13:05,90006022,2
6004-10,13:20,90006030,3
6004-10,13:20,90006015,4
6004-10,13:20,90006019,5    
6004-10,13:30,90006034,6
6004-10,13:40,90006033,7
6004-10,13:40,90006002,8
```

is there a way to obtain this output:

```
400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,,90002107,4
400102-25,,90002111,5
400102-25,7:05,90002106,6
6004-10,13:05,90006017,1
6004-10,,90006022,2
6004-10,13:20,90006030,3
6004-10,,90006015,4
6004-10,,90006019,5
6004-10,13:30,90006034,6
6004-10,,90006033,7
6004-10,13:40,90006002,8
```

I want to remove the duplicates of field 2 (comma separated) and replace by comma, but keep the first and last record of each sequence as determined by column 4.

I think the result can be partly obtained by

```
 awk '{FS=OFS=","} { if(!seen[$1 $2]++) print $0 ; else print $1,","$3, $4 } END{print}' input
```

but this is not solving everything. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are there always no more than 2 consecutive occurrences of a given $2? What if the same $2 had different $1s - ignore the $1s or handle it differently? Why are `400102-25,,90002111,5` and `400102-25,7:05,90002106,6` in the output (and others)? Clean it up to be accurate or explain why some blocks of output follow different rules than others if it is already correct.

Comment: @EdMorton There may be more than 2 consecutive occurrences of a given $2. $1 will always be identical for a sub-cycle of $5 (e.g. 1 to 6, or 1 to 7). What is important here is to make sure that first and last occurrence of a sub-cycle of $5 is always kept, while all repetitions of $2 are being removed. 
A-ray is providing the correct code below. However, it'll not remove >2 consecutive occurrences of a given $2 (which is consistent with my stated problem anyway - my bad).

Comment: I have edited the input and output files according to the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution makes several assumptions. That the first field is the same for the sequence of numbers from 1 to ... , that the first field is the same width (number of characters) for every sequence and that the first field is in sorted order. It does not use the last field to determine the group of records but determines that by the first field instead.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;

while (<DATA>) {
    my ($key, @tmp) = split /,/;
    push @{ $data{$key} }, \@tmp;
}

for my $key (sort keys %data) {
    my $aref = $data{$key};
    my $end = $aref->[-1][0];

    for my $rec (reverse @$aref[1 .. $#$aref - 1]) {
        if ($rec->[0] eq $end) {
            $rec->[0] = ''; 
        }
        else {
            last;   
        }
    }
    my $beg = $aref->[0][0];

    for my $rec (@$aref[1 .. $#$aref - 1]) {
        if ($rec->[0] eq $beg) {
            $rec->[0] = ''; 
        }
        else {
            $beg = $rec->[0];
        }
    }
    for my $line (@$aref) {
        print join ",", $key, @$line;   
    }
}


__DATA__
400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,6:50,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,7:00,90002107,4
400102-25,7:05,90002111,5
400102-25,7:05,90002106,6
600004-10,13:05,90006017,1
600004-10,13:05,90006022,2
600004-10,13:20,90006030,3
600004-10,13:20,90006015,4
600004-10,13:30,90006034,5
600004-10,13:40,90006033,6
600004-10,13:40,90006002,7
```

Output

```
400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,,90002107,4
400102-25,,90002111,5
400102-25,7:05,90002106,6
600004-10,13:05,90006017,1
600004-10,,90006022,2
600004-10,13:20,90006030,3
600004-10,,90006015,4
600004-10,13:30,90006034,5
600004-10,,90006033,6
600004-10,13:40,90006002,7
```

### **Update**

To adjust to your new data requirements, I took out the hash and used an array instead, (to retain the original order of the input file). Note the command you would use to run the program would be something like:

```
perl test.pl dat3.txt
```

where `test.pl` is your program name and `dat3.txt` is the input file to process.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @data = [split /,/, <>];
my $i = $data[0][3];

while (<>) {
    my @temp = split /,/;
    if ($temp[3] == ++$i) {
        push @data, \@temp; 
    }
    else {
        process(@data);
        @data = \@temp;
        $i = $data[0][3];   
    }
}

process(@data);

sub process {
    my @data = @_;

    my $end = $data[-1][1];
    for my $rec (reverse @data[1 .. $#data - 1]) {
        if ($rec->[1] eq $end) {
            $rec->[1] = ''; 
        }
        else {
            last;   
        }
    }
    my $beg = $data[0][1];

    for my $rec (@data[1 .. $#data - 1]) {
        if ($rec->[1] eq $beg) {
            $rec->[1] = ''; 
        }
        else {
            $beg = $rec->[1];
        }
    }
    print map join(",", @$_), @data;
}
```

Output is:

```
400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,,90002107,4
400102-25,,90002111,5
400102-25,7:05,90002106,6
6004-10,13:05,90006017,1
6004-10,,90006022,2
6004-10,13:20,90006030,3
6004-10,,90006015,4
6004-10,,90006019,5
6004-10,13:30,90006034,6
6004-10,,90006033,7
6004-10,13:40,90006002,8
```

Comment: I cannot have your script to work on MacOS (which does have perl, perl5.16, perl5.18 in the /usr/bin directory). I get this error message `Name "main::DATA" used only once: possible typo at script.pl line 7. readline() on unopened filehandle DATA at script.pl line 7.`

Comment: DATA is the __DATA__ file included at the bottom of the script. DATA is often used in demonstration programs (like mine above) rather than an actual file. If you had included it with the script, as above, the program would have run OK. In your situation, if your input was in `dat.txt`, your command line would look like: `perl script.pl dat.txt` and the `while` loop would have been `while (<>)` without the DATA as above. Seeing from your _updated_ data example, my assumption that the groups were in ascending order is false. The program would need s few changes using perhaps `Tie::IxHash`

Comment: Thank you for this instruction (and the script, of course), now it works very well. Except for the sorting it does, as you point out, which means that the output has a different sorting compared to the input (after my data updates).

Comment: @Eocene See my updated section - it will retain the order of the input file.

Comment: Yes I see it now! It does the job flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`awk` to the rescue

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} 
            {if(a[$1]==$2) $2=""; 
             else a[$1]=$2}1' file       

400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,,90002107,4
400102-25,7:05,90002111,5
400102-25,,90002106,6
600004-10,13:05,90006017,1
600004-10,,90006022,2
600004-10,13:20,90006030,3
600004-10,,90006015,4
600004-10,13:30,90006034,5
600004-10,13:40,90006033,6
600004-10,,90006002,7
```

Note that your sample output sometime removes the first instance of the duplicates not the second.  This will leave the first and remove the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, this solution does not accommodate the requirement that the _first_ and _last_ occurrence of each $5 cycle should be kept.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood that part.  However, the logic is destructive (not reversible) since you may never know what was removed from for example in this line `6004-10,,90006033,7`  13.30 or 13.40

Answer (score 1):

**Update**:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}
function w(k){
    for(i in a){
        s=split(a[i],t)
        delete a[i]
    }
    for(i=1;i<=s;i+=4){
        if((k || $1!=t[1])&& i+3!=s){
            t[i+1]=""
        }else{
            t[i+5]=""
        }
        print t[i],t[i+1],t[i+2],t[i+3]
    }
}
{if($1$2 in a){a[$1$2]=a[$1$2]","$0}else{w();a[$1$2]=$0}}
END{w(1)}' file

400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,,90002107,4
400102-25,,90002111,5
400102-25,7:05,90002106,6
6004-10,13:05,90006017,1
6004-10,,90006022,2
6004-10,13:20,90006030,3
6004-10,,90006015,4
6004-10,,90006019,5
6004-10,13:30,90006034,6
6004-10,,90006033,7
6004-10,13:40,90006002,8
```

Comment: This is actually the correct code to my originally stated problem. My bad I omitted to include examples where $2 is being repeated >2 times consecutively. Please note that I've edited the original input and output to reflect this. Is there a way to modify the code to take this into account as well?

Answer (score 0):

For lua-shell, write like this:

```
wws$ `cat demo/7.lua
vim:open("demo/7.txt")
lnum_of_b=new()     --line count of block
lineid = 0
function collect()
    last_id = -1
    bid = 0     --block id
    for i = 0, vim.lmax do
        vim:Gn(i)
        :$
        if(vim:atoi() -1 ~= last_id) 
            bid = bid + 1
            lnum_of_b[bid] = 0;
        lnum_of_b[bid] = lnum_of_b[bid] + 1 
        last_id = vim:atoi()
    end
end
function do_block(lnum)
    prev_time = ""
    for i = 1, lnum do
        vim:Gn( lineid )
        :f,wvf,y:
        if( vim:clipboard() == prev_time)
            if i == lnum then vim:k()   end
            :^f,wvf,hx: 
        else prev_time = vim:clipboard();
        lineid = lineid + 1
    end
end

collect()
for i = 1, #blocks do   do_block( lnum_of_b[i] )    end

vim:print()
```

here is the a demo on my machine:

```
wws$ source demo/7.lua
400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,,90002107,4
400102-25,,90002111,5
400102-25,7:05,90002106,6
600004-10,13:05,90006017,1
600004-10,,90006022,2
600004-10,13:20,90006030,3
600004-10,,90006015,4
600004-10,13:30,90006034,5
600004-10,,90006033,6
600004-10,13:40,90006002,7
```

I think i didn't mistake your meaning: you want the last line of a block to be keeped and turn to delelte the repeated line beyond it. Yes?
the script above is not the best, because luashell is far from complete, but it can fulfil the aim in awkward measure.
And this is just his philosophy: you can always accomplish the goals.

Answer (score 0):

**Some import points**

```
awk '{FS=OFS=","} { if(!seen[$1 $2]++)
```

..
replace `FS=OFS=","` with `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}`  or possible declarations can be made outside your awk statement

remove `++` from your array `seen[$1 $2]++`.. this `++` gaves the variable a counter value

A short one liner below might work perhaps

```
awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' '{if(($1 in a) && (a[$1]==$2)){$2="";print}else{print;a[$1]=$2;}}'
```

output

```
400102-25,6:50,90005002,1
400102-25,,90005004,2
400102-25,7:00,90002109,3
400102-25,,90002107,4
400102-25,7:05,90002111,5
400102-25,,90002106,6
600004-10,13:05,90006017,1
600004-10,,90006022,2
600004-10,13:20,90006030,3
600004-10,,90006015,4
600004-10,13:30,90006034,5
600004-10,13:40,90006033,6
600004-10,,90006002,7
```